# rails i18n redis ERR unknown command [] railscast 256

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rails-i18n

Following this RailsCast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends but using Rails 5.2, I raise this error :

```
Redis::CommandError in Pages#home<br>
ERR unknown command '[]'
```

**In config/initializers/i18n_backend.rb**

`TRANSLATION_STORE = Redis.new` seems causing this problem.

Whereas `TRANSLATION_STORE = {}` works like a charm.

But without Redis!

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is defined here:
https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/key_value.rb#L25-L30

I haven't investigated redis 4 but it seems that these methods has been removed.
The solution is to patch the Redis gem and add these methods to the redis.

```
# config/initializers/redis.rb
class RedisHash
  def initialize(redis)
    @redis = redis
  end

  def [](key)
    @redis.get(key)
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    @redis.set(key, value)
  end  
end

Redis.current = Redis.new(host: 127.0.0.1,
                          port: 6379,
                          db: 0,
                          thread_safe: true)

# config/initializers/i18n.rb
I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(RedisHash.new(Redis.current))
```

This code above is sample initializer. It works with the newest version of redis 4.3.5

I've tested also redis-store/redis-i18n and it also works with the newest redis versions but in my opinion this implementation enforces huge overload on redis.

**EDIT**:
Due to the redis contributors [answer][1]

[1]: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/997#issuecomment-871302883 I've updated my solution

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer I know, but I had a similar problem after upgrading redis gem from 3.3.1 to 4.0.2

I set it back to 3.3.1 and it got fixed. Odd thing for me was that the problem only occurred in the production environment.

I am using a chained backend

`I18n.backend= I18n::Backend::Chain.new(
      I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(Redis.current),
      I18n.backend
  )`

Comment: Gave you solved the problem? I had the same.

Comment: sorry , have not tried again, we are still using Redis 3.3.1